# What's wrong with my Hilbert curve?

Tags: javascript, geometry, hilbert-curve

I have a Javascript library to plot points on a [Hilbert curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve), but something's wrong with the point determination.

I've written a test page that plots 256 points on a path. While it should look like [this](http://corte.si/posts/code/hilbert/portrait/index.html), instead it's coming out like this:

[image: There appears to be some discontinuity.]

You can inspect the source behind the page at http://jsbin.com/oheloc/1/edit (for kicks, unlock the recursion depth and raise it higher than the points exponent to see the whole path get WAY more deformed).

What's wrong with this picture? I think it's something to do with (at least) one of the quadrant transformations being incorrect, but I can't figure out what it should be.

Comment: You'd be much more likely to get help if you'd set up your code in jsbin or jsfiddle.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, but your code looks a lot like [this code on github](https://github.com/chrisdew/jshilbert).  That one has an issue logged against it that sounds suspiciously similar to the bug you're seeing.

Comment: Oh, ha ha I see you found that too :-)

Comment: Indeed, this is my fork of that code on Github, with the code refactored to do the same (broken) thing more concisely. This bug's been around for a year, I figure it's high time to fix it.

Comment: Well it's hard for me to map the way I think about the Hilbert curve over what this code does. It seems like there's a basic flaw in the way that it does the "turns" in the recursion. It works for depth 1 and 2, but starts breaking at 3. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/zGLKF/3/) is a fiddle done the way I understand it.  Note that I stay away from floating point in that, letting the SVG renderer do the work.

Comment: Also my jsfiddle runs *way* faster than that floating-point code.

Comment: You know, honestly, I agree that this code is overcomplicated and inefficient. My initial plan was to figure out the mistake in their implementation and just fix that, but the more I think about it, the more I realize that things would probably be better off if I just cut out their whole objects-and-recursion approach entirely.